# Properties: Left of the colon

Tags: knowledge, word-property

Here are three short 'property' puzzles I wrote.

In each puzzle the words to the left of the colon all have a (non-trivial) property that the word to the right of the colon does not have. What is that property? Note that it is a different property in each puzzle, and that they are ordered roughly in increasing difficulty.

1. DANGLE, HEIGHT, LEASE, RANGE, SELECTION, TRAP, TRUSTIES : EARTH
2. CARBON, COPPER, IRON, NEON, SILICON, TIN, XENON : GOLD
3. ADJUST, ALHAMBRA, CALAIS, DRAMA, MAYOR, SMOKES, PANIC : ADVISE

An answer containing the solution to all three will be accepted.

Comment: Welcome on Puzzling.SE. Since you have created three puzzles, you might consider to create three different topics to present each of them.

Comment: @Evargalo Due to how short they are (and their similar puzzle structure) I thought it would be better to post them as one puzzle. Are there any guidelines on this?

Comment: I think it's fine that they're together! I agree that posting them separately would probably be a bit too "spread-out". (It would be nice if there was something linking them together to justify having them in the same question, but that does seem a bit hard to do for this type of puzzle.)

Comment: I would just like to note that, while people enjoy these types of puzzles, they oft seem to me to be at risk of being too arbitrary. In general, for a puzzle such as this, one can find many number of differences between the properties of the word on the right and words on the left, therefore, there are frequently several possible answers. And in my (short) experience here, the OPs usually don't care about that and insist that the right answer is only the one they imagined, which doesn't leave a very good feeling. Eg, 1st puzzle: words on left  start with a consonant, word on the right not.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**First puzzle**

> New words can be formed by **placing the first letter at the end**. (e.g. DANGLE → ANGLED).
>
>  EARTH has the reverse property: it becomes a new word by placing the final letter in front (HEART)
>
>  **Full list:**
>  DANGLE → ANGLED
>  HEIGHT → EIGHTH
>  LEASE → EASEL
>  RANGE → ANGER
>  SELECTION → ELECTIONS
>  TRAP → RAPT
>  TRUSTIES → RUSTIEST

**Second puzzle**

> Words can be formed using **element symbols** (e.g. C-Ar-B-O-N).
>
>  GOLD does not have this property, since neither *G* nor *Go* is an existing element symbol.
>
>  **Full list:**
>  CARBON → C-Ar-B-O-N
>  COPPER → C-O-P-P-Er
>  IRON → Ir-O-N
>  NEON → Ne-O-N
>  SILICON → Si-Li-C-O-N
>  TIN → Ti-N
>  XENON → Xe-N-O-N

**Third puzzle**

> **Biblical names** can be formed form the words after removing one letter (e.g.: ADJUST - T = JUDAS)
>
>  ADVISE does not have this property.
>
>  **Full list:**
>  ADJUST - T = JUDAS
>  ALHAMBRA - L = ABRAHAM
>  CALAIS - L = ISAAC
>  DRAMA - R = ADAM
>  MAYOR - O = MARY
>  SMOKES - K = MOSES
>  PANIC - P = CAIN

Comment: Great! This was my first puzzle posted, do you have any feedback/comments on it?

Comment: Gur vqrn jnf gung 'nqivfr' jnf pybfr ohg abg pybfr rabhtu gb pbagnva 'qnivq'. ohg znlor hfvat 'nqivfrq' vafgrnq, sbezvat 'qnivq' jvgu gjb yrggref fcner, jbhyq unir orra orggre.

Comment: @JMarza Nice first puzzle, I liked it! Keep them coming ;)

Comment: I like that there's a twist on the 1st and 3rd ones, but why not the 2nd?  Or did we miss something?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I thought GOLD was fitting "bire bgure ryrzragf orpnhfr uvfgbevpnyyl nypurzvfgf unir gevrq gb znxr tbyq sebz bgure ryrzragf ohg snvyrq". But it's more flavour than a twist. Something I will work on for next time.